# Extracting comments from multiple zip files with python

Tags: python, zip, comments

i started learning python a few months ago, and I'm trying to solve a challenge that requires me to go through many [2,000~] zip files in a folder, collect all the comments in them and find a clue.

The part that I'm struggling with is the extraction of the comments.

I imported the zipfile module, but I'm not sure how to make it go through all the files in the folder that contain the zip files, and collect all the comments.

I'm using pycharm, and I would't mind if the result will be in the preview area insde pycharm or exported to a new .txt file

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i in os.listdir(path_to_folder):
        if i.endswith('.zip'):
            << Your code here>>
```

Try this and let me know if any issues

Comment: You're missing a bracket at the end of your second line. Also, I don't think your 'or' is placed correctly, you haven't posted two solutions?

Comment: I have edited the code now try and let me know . whether you are looking for the same.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the answer, but my real problem is extracting the comment about the zip file, i got to the direcory and looped through the files all right, but i cant seem to find a command that will allow me to get the comment of the zipfile (and append it to a list or new file for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

For looping over files, I tend to use the glob module in python. It returns a list of files that match the string you specify ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)). Then once you have the list of files, you can loop over them and run some function/code on each one in turn.

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*.zip")

for f in list_of_files:
    ***insert code for each zip file****
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments in individual files can be accessed using getinfo function in zipfile module, i.e., getinfo(file_name).comment() as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792923/python-reading-a-zip-file-comment).