# Python, reading a zip file comment

Tags: python, zip

how do I read a ZIP file comment with python?
I tried using

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('D:\XXX\Desktop\MyZip.zip', 'r')
comment = archive.comment("firstobj.1")
```

but it does not work...
Any help would be appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`archive.comment()` takes no argument and returns the comment of the archive itself.

To get a comment on an item, get it first using `getinfo`, then take the `comment` field:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(r'D:\XXX\Desktop\MyZip.zip', 'r')
print(archive.getinfo("firstobj.1").comment)
```